# rn-fetch-blob is breaking after assemble release

Tags: android, react-native, file, rn-fetch-blob

i am using rn-fetch-blob to download the files to my local directory.
`npx react-native run-android` is running as expected, but after assemble release it fails.

the debug apk is also working.

here is the package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  }
```

and here is the implementation of the package.

```
const hanldePress = async () => {
    requestGet(`/getswpvideo?org_id=${envConst.orgID}`).then((res) => {
      if (res?.data?.body) {
        let videoLength = res?.data?.body?.length;
        res?.data?.body?.forEach(async (i) => {
          const nameArr = i.category_name.split("/")
          const name = nameArr.pop();
          if (!await RNFS.exists(`${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${envConst.videoFolderName}/${name}`)) {
            const { config, fs, } = RNFetchBlob
           
            let options = {
              fileCache: true,
              addAndroidDownloads: {
                useDownloadManager: true,
                notification: false,
                path: `${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${envConst.videoFolderName}/${name}`,
              }
            }
           try {
            await config(options).fetch('GET', i.category_name)
            videoLength--;
           } catch (error) {
            ToastAndroid.show('Something went wrong!!!',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
           }
           
          } else {
            videoLength--;
            if (videoLength === 0) {
              ToastAndroid.show('Download Complete',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

error on android studio logcat:
[image]

android manifest file
[image]

Comment: Can you show your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Abe , added android manifest file

Comment: Check the readme for the project, you're missing some permissions. Near "You also might need add the following lines to AndroidManifest.xml". Also, please add code and error messages as text and not as images.